# Cloudformation: Why does RDS instance creates default security group when i am already creating one while initating RDS?

Tags: mysqli, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

This is my RDS instance, I am creating a security group which gives access to my Workbench and backend code. RDS creates default security group, which overlaps the security group i create and thus makes it not accessible. How can i stop RDS create default security group.

Here is my RDS template

```
"Resources": {
    "epmoliteDB": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
        "Properties": {
            "DBName": {"Ref": "DBname"},
            "DBSecurityGroups": [{"Ref": "DBSecurityGroup"}],
            "AllocatedStorage": "5",
            "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
            "Engine": "MySQL",
            "MasterUsername": {"Ref": "DBuser"},
            "MasterUserPassword": {"Ref": "DBpass"},
            "DBParameterGroupName": {"Ref": "epmoliteDBParameterGroup"}
        }
    },

    "DBSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": {
                "EC2SecurityGroupName": {"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}
            },
            "GroupDescription": "Frontend Access"
        }
    },

    "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription" : "Enable MYSQL access via port 3306",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                "IpProtocol": "tcp","FromPort": "3306","ToPort": "3306","CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }]
        }
    },

    "epmoliteDBParameterGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup",
        "Properties" : {
          "Description" : "Parameter group to avoid schema import errors",
          "Family" : "MySQL5.7",
          "Parameters" : {
            "log_bin_trust_function_creators": "1"
          }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly explain why a default security group is created and overlap with the one you specified. What I can tell you though is that you should really rely on `VPCSecurityGroups` which replaces the old `DBSecurityGroups` which was relevant in "EC2 Classic" (before the VPC era). Perhaps this will solve the issue.

There's an article in the doc to learn more about this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.Compare.